# linux ethernet frame socket clarification

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to understand  below lines in the sample socket code in found in google.

```
struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));
```

`struct ether_header *eh`  -> So far in know `*eh` used to access the struct variable

i just want to understand these assignment

1. `(struct ether_header *) sendbuf;`
2. `(struct iphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));`

Comment: What is it in these assignments that you don't understand?

Comment: I just want to understand this line 
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));

Comment: first one is accessing ethernet header ptr, and next is accessing the iphdr ptr. ( ethernet packet contains IP packet)

Comment: You know about pointers, right?

Answer (score 4):

In the first line

```
(struct ether_header *) sendbuf;
```

the variable `sendbuf` is cast to a pointer to the `struct ether_header`, you can read more about casting [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Statements/Variables/Type_Casting)

The second line

```
(struct iphdr *) (sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));
```

it's adding `sizeof(struct ether_header)` to the pointer `sendbuf`, by doing that, it reaches the memory zone after the one occupied by the pointer to the struct ether_header , which seems to contain a pointer to the struct `iphdr`

This is the schematic representation of sendbuf

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|    eh                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|    iph = eh + sizeof(struct ether_header)            |
+------------------------------------------------------+

                   -- sendbuf --
```

Comment: Hm, won't that increment by a multiple of the ether_header struct size without a char * cast to sendbuf?

Answer (score 1):

first one is accessing ethernet header ptr, and next is accessing the iphdr ptr. ( ethernet packet contains IP packet)